# Where is the line on serial voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

I participate in essentially one single tag on StackOverflow, and will often go through periods of time where I'm looking at new questions as they come in. Recently, I've found myself answering a number of questions at the same time as one particular other user.

I legitimately believe the other user's answers to be wrong (and therefore unhelpful), so I would normally downvote them. But I am afraid that this will be seen as targeted harassment or vandalism, since I'd be placing multiple downvotes on the same user over a short period of time.

Is this a legitimate concern? Is there some other way to convey (both to the asker and to the world at large) that I believe these answers are wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned. Just make sure you're voting on the post, not the user.

Comment: As far as I understand things, the "line" is proprietary information that us mere mortals should never know, and there is good reason for this set up -- so that the site can minimize users who try to "game" the system by doing just enough serial down-voting to avoid detection or penalty.

Comment: The "line" is when you specifically go looking for posts written by them (whether by visiting their profile, searching for their posts or browsing tags they frequent with the intention of finding their posts). You shouldn't worry if you don't do that. Letting the fact that a post was written by them affect or determine your vote is also bad, but I don't think that falls within the definition of "serial voting".

Comment: Voting is personnal. If it's not a drive by vote on multiple question in a short time frame, the carpet-downvoting. For attention on answer, If the question is good enought or an answer is worthy enought, you can post a Bounty to reward an existing answer. This will bring attention to a Question/Answer, perhaps you can provide a great answer that will radiate some light.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are voting naturally, as things come in, you should not be concerned.

The general idea is that serial voting is when you're specifically targeting a user. You're not only not targeting the user, instead voting on the post's contents (from your description), you're also doing so organically and "in the wild" rather than, for example, going through their profile.

Even if you were voting on posts in their profile "naturally", as in on the content and not just that they posted it, going through their profile would still be targeting them.

---

As for conveying that you believe answers are wrong, it's going to depend on a few factors:

If you think the answer can be fixed, then perhaps suggest the fix in the comments.

If you can't figure out why the user suggested a solution, ask in the comments for clarification.

If you can't imagine a conversation not sounding like you're looking down on them, or targeting *them* rather than the content... Better for you to just downvote and go. If you don't feel you can word the problem well, or if you (for whatever reason) think the user won't take the criticism well, this is the option you'll want.

And naturally... You don't want to do this on *every* post of theirs. If it's just blatantly wrong, and you know for sure that it is, just downvote and go. The votes will speak for themselves. If the user can fix it, it'd be nice of you to suggest it. But if you're making suggestions on every post, they might start to feel targeted, even if they *know* it's just that you're in the same tag at the same time.

For the most part, if you're friendly about it and open-minded if they point out something you didn't think of, you should be fine doing that.